# Better solution for existing sql query

Tags: sql

I have table like this:

```
type       | date       | id
-----------------------------
1          | 2012-01-01 | 1
2          | 2012-01-01 | 2
1          | 2012-02-02 | 3
2          | 2012-02-02 | 4
```

I need to build query that will pick all "up-to-date" distinct values of type ( in this example it will be records with id's 3 and 4). Now i have this solution :

```
select * from test t1 where date = 
(select max(date) from test t2 where t2.type = t1.type ) order by type, date desc
```

I am embarrassed by the presence of nested select, maybe there is more elegant solution ?

Comment: Which RDBMS?  This is perfect *(imho)* for MySQL for example.  There are alternatives in other dialects.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/612231/944681)

Comment: Is what you are really asking is... what is the latest date activity for a given type -- thus resulting in returning records ID 3 & 4?

Comment: subselect aren't necessary a bad thing, you know? no need to be embarrassed ;)

Comment: 2DRapp, no, the latest date activity for each type

Comment: ID 3 and 4 contains the latest date for each type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you didn't mention the RDBMS you are using, try this one. will work on most RDBMS.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  type, MAX(DATE) maxDAte
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY type
        ) b ON a.type = b.type AND
                a.DATE = b.maxDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97cdc/2)

or if you RDBMS supports `Window Function`

```
SELECT type, date, id
FROM
(
    SELECT type, date, id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type
                                ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM tableNAme
) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf52b/1)

Comment: +1 : This is simply an Algebraic Re-arrangement of the same algorithm. It should be noted, however, that some RDBMS optimise this better than the OPs suggestion. *(And I've never known this to be **worse** than the OPs suggestion.)*  *[I'd +1 the `ROW_NUMBER()` alternative too, but it won't let me ;)]*

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, this could work also:

```
select type, max(date), max(id)
from your_table
group by type
```

but notice that it will work only if you are absolutely sure that dates and ids are always increasing. If this is not the case, `max(date)` and `max(id)` could be on two different rows. Use this only if you know what you are doing! If not, there's nothing wrong with nested queries.

Comment: Nice approach, i should think about this.